# Can I break the fall of an Enderman with water?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I am planning on building an XP farm and I am wondering which route to choose.

I have the basic setup figured out, I am going to use gravity as main transportation. There will be a tunnel from where I am standing 30 blocks up. Above that the main spawning cubes will be.

To make this as simple as possible I want to just let them fall from above. 5 blocks above the ground I want to make a 4 high - 2 wide layer of water where mobs will fall in. I bet this will break their fall and they will reach the ground only with minor damage so there are easy to kill. To make the Enderman a little easier to kill I will have a crusher using sticky pistons on the 3the 3th block.

Main Question:

I am wondering if the Enderman will TP away when they reach the 4 high area of water, my main guess is that they will.

Else I would have to break the fall each 4 blocks or so. A lot more works as I would have to work with open trap doors and pistons.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Water will not work, sorry.. they will either die or tp away depending on existing damage.
but what is stopping you from going with the vine method? I know it can get a little tedious making all those circles, but it is totally worth it. Also gotta have sticky pistons..

It's a little lengthy but it's amazing.

You can get to 50 in about 5-10 minutes.

Basically, sticky pistons with a block on the end and pressure plates will push enderman off platforms down a circular ring that is bridged with 4 spaced "rings" that have vines on them. The vines, in turn reset the fall speed until they fall down into the next level

Comment: Do you have a reference for the "vine method"?

Comment: www.youtube.com/watch?v=NjO9rfYCgJc                its a little lengthy but its amazing. you can get to 50 in about 5-10 minutes.       basically... sticky pistons with a block on the end and pressure plates will push enderman off platforms down a circular ring that is bridged with 4 spaced "rings" that have vines on them. The vines, in turn reset the fall speed until they fall down into the next level.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting the vines method. You were the first one with the answer that's why I accepted this one.

Answer (score 1):

Also a possible way to build a pretty good xp farm without using the end is this:

Find yourself a zombie or skeleton spawner. Gather the mobs with water and drop them a pretty far distance. (They have to survive it, but just barely.)
Create a lock with pistons, so that the creeps don't drop on top of you while you are collecting the xp.

Create a hole in the shaft with a door in it and brew splash health potions.

Now you can idle near the spawner and when you think there are enough mobs, close the shaft's entrance, go to your door and throw a potion down.

Since skeleton and zombies take damage from splash health potions you get the credit for the kill and the xp.

The advantage of this method is that you can do something else while you are iddling and don't have to kill all of the mobs that spawn at once.

Comment: This is an excellent method and I use it in conjunction with my end farm. I play on a server and often it is already in use. I would prefer the end farm every time though. It is easily 5-10x faster for experience. (even with 4 different spawner entry points)

Comment: Ya sure, but if you are alone and don't want to cheat it can be very much work to build an end farm all by yourself.

Comment: I have done this totally legit, alone. Yeah it took a little while, but it was fun. I have a triple monior setup and was watching a movie and looking at the refrenced video while building all at the same time :P It flew by.

Answer (score 1):

Use [vines](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Vines) to slow their fall.

See what's done in this video: